# JS Timezones not current

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have just created a blog script, but when I add a comment.
The timestamp in the database is `2014-07-29 18:55:00` even that the clock on my PC is `2014-07-29 20:55:00`.

So I would like to change the time according to the timezone.

So I tried with this code (where timestamp is `2014-07-29 18:55:00`):

```
var UTC = moment.tz(timestamp, "UTC");
timestamp = UTC.clone().tz(timezone).format('YYYY/MM/DD H:mm:ss');
```

Note: `window.timezone` is set using the following code:

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var timezone = tz.name();
```

The time I want to get out is `2014/07/29 20:55:00`, but I get this out: `2014/07/29 17:53:47`

I am using the following libraries for this above code:

- https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect
- http://momentjs.com/timezone/
- http://momentjs.com/

Hope that someone understands whats going on.

NOTE: I live in `Europe/Denmark` which have the timezone `UTC/GMT +2 hours`

Comment: moment and moment-timezone version please?  Are you loading the time zone data?

Comment: @MattJohnson, `Moment.js 2.7.0` and `Moment-Timezone 0.1.0-2014e`. And I am not sure what kind of timezone data you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to script, moment-timezone requires data to function.  If you don't have the data loaded, in version 0.1.x it will use the local time zone - as if you just called `moment()` without any `tz` specified.  [This has been fixed](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/106) for the upcoming 0.2.0 release, such that it gives an error instead of silently doing the wrong thing.

Normally, you could use [the data builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) to just provide data for the time zones you were interested in.  However, it is currently offline because the format of the data changed in the last release and the author has not yet had time to complete the required updates.

In the meantime, you can use one of the "data-included" versions, downloadable at the top of [the main page](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) - for example, use `moment-timezone-2010-2020.js` instead of just `moment-timezone.js`.

Also, you since you're using [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) - you should test the value returned by `jstz.determine()` to make sure it is indeed the time zone you are expecting.  The +2 offsets are notoriously difficult to test for.  See some of [the known issues](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/issue/64/incorrect-middle-eastern-timezones).

Comment: What they don't make clear on the website, and what I struggled with for a while, is that you don't need BOTH moment-timezone.js AND moment-timezone-2010-2020.js. You just need moment-timezone-2010-2020.js. If you load them both like I was doing, with moment-timezone.js first, you will not get the zone data. They should make their documentation a little more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could [set the timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

```
moment().tz("Europe/Denmark").format();
```

Comment: This results in the timezone from the database. This doesn't convert the time from the old timezone to my timezone. Thanks anyways.